# How can a closed application perform periodic work with WorkManager on Android 10?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager, android-10.0

I have asked a question about periodic work here: [How can a closed application receive periodic broadcasts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479482/how-can-a-closed-application-receive-periodic-broadcasts). The answer has been to use `WorkManager` and this has been a great solution on Android 9.

On another device using Android 10 the solution of this former question does not work anymore. This seems to be a common problem. The question here has been upvoted a lot, but its single answer is not accepted and it also didn't help me: [WorkManager not working when app killed in Android 10 although working fine till version 9 (Pie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147401/workmanager-not-working-when-app-killed-in-android-10-although-working-fine-till).

Therefore I would like to formulate a specific problem for Android 10. Does anyone know how to solve it?

1. Create an empty activity in AndroidStudio with `File`->`New`->`New Project...`->`Empty Activity`->`Language: Java, SDK: API 28`.
2. Add a class MyWorker with the following content:

```
package org.test.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

public class MyWorker extends Worker
{
    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params)
    {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork()
    {
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Play tone to show that the worker is working
                ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 200);
                        toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_EMERGENCY_RINGBACK, 1000);

                // Also display some message
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 1000);

        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

3. Modify the class `MainActivity` to have the following content:

```
package org.test.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;
import androidx.work.WorkRequest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WorkRequest workRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest);
    }
}
```

4. Install and run the application. The tone from `MyWorker::doWork` is played and the respective toast is displayed.
5. Now swipe the activity up to close it.

Expectation: The periodic work should continue to be executed like it has been on Android 9.

Actual behaviour: Nothing happens anymore. The `WorkManager` has obviously been stopped.

Question: How can I modify the example to work on Android 10?

Comment: "The periodic work should continue to be executed like it has been on Android 9" -- not necessarily. Device manufacturers have screwed up their task management on Android 9 and earlier as well. Also note that your test is not particularly reliable (process might end or `Handler` might be GC'd before the time elapses, might have problems from trying to display a `Toast` without an `Activity`, etc.). Use Logcat to log a message before returning `Result.success()`.

Comment: And, rolling all the way back to your premise, `WorkManager` is not guaranteed to keep your process around to be able to receive broadcasts. My reference to polling using `WorkManager` was not to receive broadcasts, but to poll for some system state.

Comment: @CommonsWare But in the example given here, I do not try to receive broadcasts. I play a tone and display a toast. "Polling some system state" should be equivalent at least to playing tones, shouldn't it. So when my `WorkManager` cannot reliably play tones when the activity is closed, what can I use instead?

Comment: My device is a Samsung Tab S4. Do you really think that the same app might work on another device?

Comment: ""Polling some system state" should be equivalent at least to playing tones, shouldn't it" -- since `doWork()` is already running on a background thread, you would not need `Handler`. I do not know why your example is using a `Handler` or playing tones. Use Logcat. "So when my WorkManager cannot reliably play tones when the activity is closed, what can I use instead?" -- I would start by using Logcat instead of playing tones. Then, I would make sure that I am on the latest production version of the `WorkManager` library.

Comment: Then, if you still do not see evidence of your `doWork()` getting called every 15 minutes after the task removal, create a project that reproduces those findings and file a bug report. In the end, even `WorkManager` will be unreliable on some devices. A Samsung is fairly mainstream, though, and so the team behind `WorkManager` should be, um, working to get it to be reliable there.

Comment: @CommonsWare Your comments have been very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been nothing wrong with the code or the project setup. My device has been in power saving mode and this obviously has prevented the periodic `WorkManager` tasks when the activity had been closed. Leaving power saving mode has solved the problem.